# Trying to get PermissionSet Name from PermissionSetAssignment SOQL in Apex

Tags: apex, soql

When I run SOQL in the query editor:

```
SELECT Id, PermissionSet.Id, PermissionSet.Name FROM PermissionSetAssignment WHERE AssigneeId = 'xxxx'
```

I'm able to get the PermissionSet.Name in the results.

But when I run in APEX:

```
List<sObject> perms = [SELECT Id, PermissionSet.Id, PermissionSet.Name FROM PermissionSetAssignment WHERE AssigneeId = 'xxxx'];

System.debug(perms); //NO PERMISSION SET NAME IN LIST

for(sObject ps : perms){             
   System.debug(ps); 
   // LOOKS LIKE THIS: PermissionSetAssignment:{Id=XXX, PermissionSetId=XXXX}
}
```

I cannot seem to the queried **PermissionSet.Name**. Is there a specific way to get this?

Comment: why are you using `List<sObject>` versus `List<PermissionSetAssignment>`?

Comment: this is WAD - debug will not show lookup field if you just display the sobjects; @sarojbera has the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the dot notation to traverse through relationships as below.

```
List<PermissionSetAssignment> psaList = [SELECT Id, PermissionSet.Id, PermissionSet.Name FROM PermissionSetAssignment LIMIT 10];

for(PermissionSetAssignment psa: psaList){
    System.debug('PermissionSet Name '+psa.PermissionSet.Name);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @saroj